# android studio open an eclipse project,when executing Dex outcomes DexIndexOverflowException:65554

Tags: android, eclipse

I use android studio. I opened an eclipse project，and when executing Dex, I got this:

> DexIndexOverflowException:Cannot merge new index 65554 into a non-jumbo instruction.

So, I opened Setting->Compiler->Android Compilers, checked **Force jumbo mode** and then opened `project.properties`, and added `dex.force.jumbo=tre`. But, it is still not working.

I hope someone can help me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have something that extends Application try adding this code to the class

```
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer，but I don't want to use MultiDex. I just confused that when Using IntelliJ IDEA is no problem,Using Android studio comes DexIndexOverflowException.